# Matlab create a matrix with values

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix

I've written a function in matlab which generates a matrix using a loop. I was wondering if it is possible to generate the same results without a loop. X can either be a 1 x 50, 2 x 50, 3 x 50, etc... the values range from 1 to 50 incrementally for each column per row.

**For example**

> - 1 x 1 = 1,
> - 2 x 1 = 1,
> - 3 x 1 = 1,
> - 1 x 2 = 2,
> - 2 x 2 = 2,
> - 3 x 2 = 2,
> - .....................
> - 1 x 50 = 50,
> - 2 x 50 = 50,
> - 3 x 50 = 50,

**My function:**

```
function [i] = m(x)
    [a, b] = size(x);
    i = zeros(a, b);
    for c = 1 : a
        i(c, :) = (1:size(x,2));
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
output = repmat(1:size(x,2), size(x,1), 1);
```

Some alternatives are

```
output = ones(size(x,1),1)*(1:size(x,2));
```

and

```
output = cumsum(ones(size(x)),2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of repmat. I was trying out reshape all this time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
N = 3;
M = 50;
x = repmat((1:N)',M,1);
y = reshape(repmat((1:M)',1,N)',N*M,1);
%z = x.*y
z = strcat(num2str(x),'x',num2str(y),'=',num2str(x.*y))
```

This will give the same format in your question.

Answer (score 2):

One alternate to `repmat`([Luis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30414453/2111163)) is [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
out = bsxfun(@times,ones(size(x,1),1),1:size(x,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for an alternate method!